# GPS get the longitude and elevation separately

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cllocationdistance

i use this code to get gps data

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    locLabel.text = [location description];
}
```

the result look like this

> <+38.76856432, +11.99454301> +/- 100.00m (speed ......)

when i trie this  i have an error,

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    locLabel.text = [location altitude];}
```

error

> Assigng to "NSString *" from incompatible type CLLocationDistance
>   (aka double)

i want to get longitude too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get latitude and longitude separately from `location.coordinate.latitude` and `location.coordinate.longitude`.

The altitude you are receiving may be invalid.  Check the value in `location.verticalAccuracy`.  Per the documentation, "A negative value indicates that the altitude value is invalid."  Same goes for `location.horizontalAccuracy` to make sure the latitude and longitude values in location.coordinate are valid.

Answer (score 1):

The `altitude` property is of type `CLLocationDistance`, which is a `typedef` for `double`.  You are trying to assign a number to a property that is expecting a string.  You need to create a string representation of the number.  Use something like this:

```
locLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [location altitude]];
```

Comment: thank you but I have zero as a result. I think we do not get the longitude and altitude in this way

Comment: That's the correct way to access altitude data, but altitude data is not available for all location updates.